# Filling vector with emplace_back vs. std::transform

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, c++11, std

It's oversimplified code with a simple vector and class.

```
class OutputClass
{
public:
OutputClass(int x, int y);
};

std::vector<OutputClass> Convert(std::vector<int> const &input)
{
    std::vector<OutputClass> res;
    res.reserve(input.size());
    //either (1)
    for (auto const &in : input)
        res.emplace_back(in, in*in);
    return res;
    //or something like (2)
    std::transform(input.begin(), 
                   input.end(), 
                   std::back_inserter(res), 
                   [](InputClass const &in){return OutputClass(in, in*in);});
    return res;
}
```

Is there a difference in performance between those two options? Static analyzers often have a rule for replacing all raw loops with algorithms, but in this case, it seems to me that looping with emplace_back would be more efficient, as we don't need either copy or move. Or I'm wrong and they are equal in terms of performance and (2) is preferable in terms of good style and readability?

Comment: `Is there difference in performance in those two options?` You can find out by measuring.

Comment: unless there is a `back_emplacer` I would use the loop to emplace and the algorithm to insert. They express slightly different things, even if after optimizations they might be the same

Comment: Scratch my last comment. I ran the bench again on [C++ Quick Bench](https://quick-bench.com/) and the `emplace_back` version is marginally faster. When I ran the test originally I forgot to `reserve` space in the `std::vector` for the `std::transform` bench

Comment: @WBuck If you claim to have some benchmark results and link https://quick-bench.com, why not include the link to your results? I cannot reliably reproduce `emplace_back` being any faster than `std::transform`: https://quick-bench.com/q/SoJQbRCSrkd5z2Kd04kh-S6jUkE

Comment: std::transform allows you to specify an execution policy from C++17 on, allowing you to parallelize the execution. Sadly, it doesn't seem to work well with the std::back_inserter. During experimenting with this, I stumbled across the fact that for your simple example, `resize` + fill is two times as fast as `reserve` + insert. The assembly shows that clang12 and gcc10 fail to vectorize the insert-loops -- maybe they fail to prove that resizing is not needed? https://quick-bench.com/q/yKgW89g_4Q0GhYtTWIxPqs_Kzzc. (Note: The container it is running in may be limited to one core)

Comment: @He3lixxx I cannot for the life of me re-create what you're seeing. Here are my [results](https://quick-bench.com/q/ZMKwKU45ymJFgaODlExPRLh1OoA)

Comment: Seems like the main difference is that I used `DoNotOptimize(result.data())`, which should -- as far as I understand -- only force the compiler to not optimize away the contiguous object storage behind the vector, where you use `DoNotOptimize(result)`, which I'd expect to be way more aggressive in preventing optimization. If you change that, you get my results: https://quick-bench.com/q/J3b_-hDnrJ-OuSq-U88kmUc0nB4 (Note that if you only use `result.data(), the two functions are two times faster in general - around 300'000 vs 600'000 "no-op equivalents")

Comment: @He3lixxx Ahhhhhh yes, I was wondering why my results were so much slower than yours. This makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 0):

To find out whether one is significantly faster than the other in a particular use case, you can measure.

I see no benefit in enforcing the creation of vectors. Avoiding that dynamic allocation when it isn't needed can be quite good for performance. Here is an example where vectors are used, but that's not necessary:

```
OutputClass
convert(int in)
{
    return {in, in*in};
}

auto
convert_range(const auto& input)
{
    return std::ranges::transform_view(input, convert);
}

#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> input {1, 2, 3};
    auto r = convert_range(input);
    std::vector<OutputClass> output(r.begin(), r.end());
}
```